# Why does IEqualityComparer<T> require GetHashCode?

Tags: .net

I'm aware that variations on this question have been asked before, but I haven't yet found anything which addresses specifically what I'm asking.

In .NET, we have `IEqualityComparer<T>`, which has the following:

```
public interface IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    public bool Equals(T x, T y);
    public int GetHashCode(T obj);
}
```

So, my question is why this was not instead split into two interfaces, along the lines of:

```
public interface IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    public bool Equals(T x, T y);
}

public interface IHashProvider<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    public int GetHashCode(T obj);
}
```

In other words, I can see why in any situation where you will perform `GetHashCode` on an object, you will almost certainly need to know how to perform `Equals` too. Also, the definition of `Equals` is part of one of the requirement for implementing `GetHashCode` correctly (if two objects are equal, their hash codes must be equal too).

However, this doesn't seem to be true the other way around. It's not that hard to imagine situations where you care about checking if two objects are equal by some custom implementation of `Equals`, but are not performing any operations involving the hash code.

Is there any reason the interface wasn't split out similar to the above, allowing methods to require an `IHashProvider<T>` (or whatever it would be called) or `IEqualityComparer<T>` depending on whether they would or would not be using the hash code? Was it just a historical decision that would be too much hassle to change now? Or is there some reason that I'm overlooking that it's important to *always* implement `GetHashCode` alongside `Equals`?

Comment: Because this is how it was defined - a cheeky response, but true. There is also [`IComparable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx) (although it implies an ordering). Also, an implementation of IEqualityComparer could always return a constant value, say 0, and not break the contract.

Comment: There is no real reason behind that, it was just decided and implemented this way. A similar example is the reflection API - they decided to use arrays everywhere and that forces them to create a new array when ever they return one, for example in `Type.GetMethods()`. In hindsight using `IEnumerable<T>`would have been better but generics were not available at the time of .NET 1.0. `IClonable` is yet another example. They forgot to specify whether it is shallow or deep and so today the usage is discouraged because you don't know for sure what you will get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason the `IEqualityComparer<T>` has been added to the .NET framework is to allow you to customize the logic to hash-based containers in cases when you cannot modify the class with a different override of `Equals`/`GetHashCode` (say, it's in someone else's library) or you do not want to change the default implementation for any other reason - for example, for backward compatibility. This is the primary purpose of having this interface: you give it to hash containers, and they use it instead of the `Equals`/`GetHashCode` logic that comes with the object.

It appears that the platform designers did not have a use case for an `IEqualityComparer<T>` interface outside customizing hash containers. It is hard to come up with a scenario when an externally-supplied `Equals` would be useful by itself, without `GetHashCode`. The .NET platform already provides a concise mechanism for users who need to externalize a two-variable (or N-variable) checks through `Predicate<T1,T2>`, so if you want to write code that takes an equality checker from outside, you can do this:

```
void MyFunction(IEnumerable<T> one, IEnumerable<T> two, Predicate<T,T> equalityCheker) {
    foreach (var a in one) {
        foreach (var b in two) {
            if (equalityCheker(a, b)) {
                Console.WriteLine("Equal: {0} {1}", a, b);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is it was not worth it to add two separate interfaces instead of one. I highly recommend you read the article by Eric Gunnerson called "[Minus 100 points](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx)" where he goes over the costs of adding a feature to the C#. What it boils down to is separating `GetHashCode()` from `Equals()` did not get enough point to warrant it being separate interfaces.

I also recommend reading some of these articles on similar topics

- [How many Microsoft employees does it take to change a lightbulb?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/10/28/how-many-microsoft-employees-does-it-take-to-change-a-lightbulb.aspx)
- [There's no such thing as a simple feature](http://blogs.technet.com/b/kclemson/archive/2004/05/10/129544.aspx)
- [Thinking through a feature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/05/13/131116.aspx)
- [Why Doesn't OneNote have Feature X?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chris_pratley/archive/2004/01/31/65606.aspx)

Comment: This is a good point, though I'm not sure two interfaces vs. one is really the same as adding a new feature. When first creating, them, that is. Obviously going back and changing an existing interface is a different kettle of fish!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare if two **immutable** objects are equal, then it ***may*** be faster to first check if they have the same hash code. - Since the objects are immutable, their hashcode is constant, therefore it may as well be saved as part of the object's state for faster usage in dictionaries.

When you search for an object in a dictionary, the search is done by hashcode of the key, to find the correct bin, then using Equals() to find the correct key.

In other words, if you want to find or compare objects, it is often important to be able to first compare their hashcodes, therefore the equality interface should enable getting the hashcode too.

Comment: Often, yes. But what if you don't want to check hash code first (not being able to guarantee immutability for the key that you check equality on is an example of why that might be the case)? That's the idea behind the question anyway, though Scott's answer that `IEqualityComparer` was never really intended for anything except hash-based containers makes sense.